# How to add some vertices from another object to the vertex object of one object?

Tags: modeling

I have a sailboat. I made a vertex group on the sail to keep it pinned to the mast, but the mast is a different object. How can I add the vertices on the mast to the vertex group to pin them together?

[image]
https://i.gyazo.com/db001a70c7d52ce8288159a9dd0efb08.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the 2 groups and press ctrl + j.After you join them click on this set it to vertices [image]after you do that join them and then click on remove doubles so they will pin together.Hope this helps and that it's what you meant. :D